# Does anything like this toy vinyl record topper featured in Season 3 of Evil exist in the real world?

Tags: realism, props, evil

During multiple episodes of the third season of the TV series, [*Evil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_(TV_series)), Leland Townsend gifts Dr. Kurt Boggs with a vinyl record of the French children's song, [*Aloutte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alouette_(song)).

[image: Kurt Boggs]

(Jump to 2:06 Mark)

But the record also comes with a toy to place on top of the record when it's playing on the turn table and creates an animated allusion of a girl running through a field (which changes to horror versions, but that is not really relevant here).

I know there are some special records that have images that can be seen when looking flat at the record and/or "Hologram" images such as THIS [Star Wars: The Force Awakens vinyl set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCJsgpal6l8), but is there anything like this carnival-mirror-toy featured in these *Evil* episodes or are they complete fiction on writers' part?

Comment: I don't know if its possible, but maybe remove the accepted mark from my answer and put it on Michael Seifert's ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the United States (and possibly other countries), these were sold as ["Red Raven Movie Records"](https://obsoletemedia.org/red-raven-movie-records/).  They were 78 RPM records for the most part, and targeted at children;  the principle was similar to that of a zoetrope.  The multi-faceted mirror was called a "Magic Mirror", and about 20 different records were produced.

The records were printed with a larger-than-average label to accommodate the animated images. This cut into the amount of music the record could contain — runtimes were only a minute or two, compared to about five minutes for a standard 78.  (Of course, children's songs are usually quite short anyhow, so this was not a huge limitation.)

[image]
<sup>Image from "Museum of Obsolete Media" link above.</sup>

A few demonstrations can be found on Youtube:

My mother (born c. 1950) was given one of these growing up, and I have fond memories of getting the thing out and watching the animations during visits to my grandparents' house.

Comment: That;s neat that you got to experience one in person growing up! They seem pretty awesome!!

Answer (score 9):

Praxinoscope

> The praxinoscope improved on the zoetrope by replacing its narrow viewing slits with an inner circle of mirrors, placed so that the reflections of the pictures appeared more or less stationary in position as the wheel turned.
>
> Someone looking in the mirrors would therefore see a rapid succession of images producing the illusion of motion

The wiki link includes a 20th Century revival section that references these records:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxinoscope

[image]

The above video link has both praxinoscopes and anamorphoscopes.

Wikipedia had this link:

https://www.retrothing.com/2006/10/red_raven_anima.html

(This has been updated based on Michael Seifert's comment)

Comment: Cool! I have never seen one before this show! Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Technically speaking I don't think this qualifies as "anamorphic" because the mirrors on the "carousel" were flat and the images printed on the record weren't distorted.

Comment: ah, praxinoscope, that would be the proper term, will update the answer

Comment: Thank you for the more specific answer and both of you for the clarification between the two terms.